# Disable Swipe in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I have implemented a swipeable recyclerview for editing purpose. Since the cardview contains a seekbar, it conflicts with the swipe. I overcame this problem using a button in toolbar menu, pressing the button once attaches the itemtouchhelper to the recyclerview `(itemtouchhelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView))`, thereby enabling swipe for editing and after that pressing the same button again, I am attaching it to null which disables the swipe. 
`itemtouchhelper.attachToRecyclerView(null)`.
Everything works as expected but I was concerned whether I did the right thing or is there any other method I should follow? Any help in form of guide or answer on whether my method is right or wrong would be appreciated
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use nestedscrollview and then define a layout under  it and then put recycler view in it.  It will work  fine..

Comment: Please, don't put recyclerview in scrollview, you break recycling then.

Comment: Well, i don't want to disable the swipe entirely,  just toggle it.  When the user wants to edit the name in the cardview,  the user can click on a toggle button and enable swipe mode, and once the user is done editing clicking the toggle button would disable the swipe. I have done that by attaching the itemtouchhelper to a recyclerview and then to null as mentioned in my post. It is working as i want it to and i was asking whether it is the right way to do it?